# Why does the hybridization occur between the orbitals that are even under a certain symmetry operations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, group-theory

For example, in monolayers MoS$_2$, considering the prismatic coordination of the metal atom, the $d$-orbitals split into three categories:

1. {$d_{z^2}$}
2. {$d_{xy}, d_{x^2-y^2}$}
3. {$d_{xz},d_{yz}$}.

Then in the paper [Xiao et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.3144.pdf) it is said that only the hybridization between the first and the second group occurs, since they have even symmetry under the reflection in the $z$-direction (mirror plane is in $xy$-plane). Why? Does hybridization occur, for example, between the elements of the third group only as well, since they have the same odd symmetry under the mentioned reflection? What is the mathematics behind these statements?

In the same paper they say that since there is $C_3$ symmetry element present in the crystal structure, then the orbitals in the second group has to add up chirally as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(d_{x^2-y^2}\pm id_{xy}).$$

Which I also do not quite understand. To my understang, rotation by 60$^\circ$ around the $z$-axis should leave the physics and properties unchanged, meaning that the linear combination above should stay the same, i.e.

$$e^{i2\pi/3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(d_{x^2-y^2}\pm id_{xy})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(d_{x^2-y^2}\pm id_{xy}).$$

When doing algebraic manipulations, I fail to prove this. What is wrong?

Comment: OK, I guess my wrong assumption was that the phase should stay unchanged as well, however, it can in general change.